# How to create a two dimensional array that supports negative indices java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to create a two dimensional array that supports negative and positive indices from points -10,-10 to 10,10? E.g. an array to simulate an x,y graph? E.g. point -10,4 should be in the index -10,4 in the array. I did try doing this but turns out Java does not allow negative indices..

I was thinking of creating some sort of mapping that maps those coordinates to an element in the index e.g. -10,-10 maps onto the [0][0] element but wanted to know if there was something easier than this.

Comment: Easier than adjusting an index through a function which hides the implementation? That already seems a good solution.

Comment: what about a custom type which has two arrays inside (one for positive and one for negative) ? oder instead save points with a coordinate instead of having huge arrays with mostly nothing

Comment: I dare you, I double dare you, ****, to find a language that allows negative indices with its raw array type. ;-)

Comment: @jingx, How about C?

Comment: @Jack could you explain more? Don't quite get what you mean

Comment: @jingx:  OK, C is a degenerate example\*  But in the Ada programming language, an array is indexed by a _range_, and a range can include negative values.

Comment: \*there's no way in C to _declare_ an array variable such that negative indices make sense.  It's just that, C does not bound-check array accesses, and it lets you use array-access syntax on pointers, and so you can create a pointer `p` such that `p[n]` makes sense for some negative `n`.

Comment: @jameslarge  LOL +1 for TIL